# how to call an executable from R script

Tags: r

I have a CUDA code which I have compiled and have the executable of it. Now I want to call this executable from a R script and pass it arguments also from the R script itself? Is it possible? If yes, please explain how?

Comment: Surely calling a CUDA executable from R is no different from calling any other compiled executable from R?

Comment: more details are usually good - operating system, in particular, is handy when asking questions like this.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To call any external executables you can use the `system` function:

```
system("cuda_exe arg1 arg2")
```

where `cuda_exe` is the cuda executable, and `arg*` are the command line arguments passed to the script.

Comment: To pass arguments from R, you might have to construct the string to system by using "paste". Note that passing entire R objects to C code is a different problem altogether, and can't be easily done to a standalone executable.

Comment: I always use `paste` and forget about `sprintf` - I should try to remember, it will save me wearing out my comma and quote keys.

Answer (score 2):

A more cross-platform alternative than `system` is `system2`. It'll work on Windows and other systems without a `/bin/sh`.

```
system2("cuda_exe", c("arg1", "arg2"))
```

It requires no shell, but shell syntax like the `*` glob won't work, and you'll have to learn the R way of doing things, such as `list.files(pattern = ".*.csv")` instead of just `"*.csv"`. The upshot is that you won't have to fiddle with `paste()` to construct the command line.